# Setting text-decoration: none but link is still underlined

Tags: css

I'm deisgning a simple button and I don't want the text link to have an underline. I set the text-decoration to "none" as in the css below, but it still is underlined. How can I get rid of that?

```
.button {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #63D3FF;
  background-color: #000E4D;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color:white;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;  
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Save Choice</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS would work for links inside an element with the class `button`, like this:

```
<span class="button"><a href="#">Save Choice</a></span>
```

But in your HTML, the link itself has the class, so in that case, the CSS should be like this:

```
a.button {
  text-decoration: none;  
}
```